# How to create many clips in the NLA editor

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have a metarig with:

- Action 1 - for example he run with ball
- Action 2 - he walk and throw the ball

When I switch actions for metarig - ball goes wrong - he throws it while running.

How can I organize this actions with the NLA?

- Create Clip 1 with needed actions, and Clip 2 and so on...
- Except ball I have many objects, which are doing different thing dependant of the action of the metarig.

---

I use a new metarig with bones for each object - e.g. the ball has its own bone.

Answer (score -1):

The [official documentation for the NLA Editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/nla/index.html) gives you the basics of operating the UI.

How to incorporate this technology into your workflow is a little more complicated.  Likewise choosing which keyframes belong in which NLA strips depends on your experience and understanding of the mathematics of the NLA system.  You're just going to have to experiment and fool around and make plenty of mistakes.

Do not underestimate the value of setting aside time just to play around and make mistakes and then try to fix those mistakes under no time pressure and with no milestones or assets at stake.

My [explanation of how to split an action into two separate NLA strips](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WrrdFpZ-VC7taxu4iD3hZIowYvyM953iZpBwkZ78PgA) probably will be somewhat confusing on first read, but after some experimentation you should have the necessary experience to understand it and absorb the concepts within.

Comment: problem with that - NLA, can't remember different metarig action and object in the same time as they were separate groups.

for example:
I need to group strips -
1) walk and through (at that througn not same metarig animation, it's different action)
2) run and different actions

NLA mixing that and give bad effect, all is good if objects inside metarig as bones - I do this http://joxi.ru/Vrwo64MUKVK0zr

but if not - he can't grouping actions into one group for play

Comment: I do not have experience with metarig.  Since you have not posted a sample .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I can not examine your animation to see exactly what is wrong.  The problem of mixing different animations using NLAs is complex and requires experience, careful thought, and experimentation to master.

Comment: you can just imagine that:

I have actions for metarig: shoot, reload and etc.
I have actions for object near him: for example throw shield, grab bazooka and etc , object as a metarig have different actions.

for me need play definently actions in the same time:
for example action metarig 1, action shield 2, action gun1
and etc

for this I need every time clean and compile this action.
But if NLA can group them , I can choose this

Do you understand without .blend ?